# How do I express ownership semantics in D?

Tags: d

```d
struct OwnedRef(T){
    import std.typecons: Proxy;
    OwnedRefImpl!T* w;
    private this(OwnedRefImpl!T* w){
        this.w = w;
    }
    mixin Proxy!w;
}
struct OwnedRefImpl(T){
    import std.typecons: Proxy;
    static if (is(T:Object))
        alias RefT = T;
    else
        alias RefT = T*;
    private Owned!(T)* ptr;
    this(Owned!(T)* t){
        ptr = t;
    }
    bool expired(){
        return ptr is null;
    }
    auto ref get(){
        if (expired()){
            throw new Error("Access of expired OwnedRef.");
        }
        return ptr.get();
    }
    mixin Proxy!get;
}
struct Owned(T){
    import std.experimental.allocator;
    import std.typecons: Proxy;
    static if (is(T:Object)){
        alias RefT = T;
        @safe ref T get(){
            return ptr;
        }
    }
    else{
        @safe ref T get(){
            return *ptr;
        }
        alias RefT = T*;
    }
    this(Args...)(auto ref Args args){
        ptr = theAllocator.make!T(args);
        wref = new OwnedRefImpl!T(&this);
    }
    OwnedRef!(T) getRef()
    {
        if(expired())
            throw new Error("Owned is expired.");
        return OwnedRef!T(wref);
    }
    bool expired(){
        return (wref is null) || (ptr is null);
    }
    void free(){
        if(wref !is null)
            wref.ptr = null;
        theAllocator.dispose(ptr);
    }
    ~this(){
        free();
    }
    void transfer(ref this o){
        free();
        wref = o.wref;
        wref.ptr = &this;
        ptr = o.ptr;
        o.wref = null;
        o.ptr = null;
    }
    this(ref this oref)
    {
        transfer(oref);
    }
    void opAssign(ref this o){
        transfer(o);
    }
    mixin Proxy!get;
    @disable this(this);
    @disable void opAssign(this);
private:
    RefT ptr;
    OwnedRefImpl!T* wref;
}
```

This should act like `Unique` but still allows references to the object. The relationship is `1 Owned` and `N OwnedRef`. If owned goes out of scope all `OwnedRef` will become expired.

I disabled

```d
@disable this(this);
@disable void opAssign(this);
```

because I have heard that even rvalue structs might not get moved in some situations and that I can not rely on this. Because I need to transfer the pointers and I want to assure uniqueness I think I have to disable them.

Is this true?

That means I have to rely on `opAssign(ref this)` and `this(ref this)` and the `transfer`method.

What happens if I need this in a container like a hashmap?

```d
Owned!int[int] map;
```

I can not do

```d
map[42] = Owned!int(42);
```

because the rvalue constructor and rvalue opAssign have been deleted.

But I also can not do

```d
auto o = Owned!int(42);
map[42] = o;
```

Why is this not possible?

Also if I try

```d
auto oi = Owned!int(42);
map[42].tansfer(oi);
```

This throws a `Range violation` and I am not sure why. I assume that the problem is that the `Owned!int` hasn't been initialized yet.